# JADE, Nodejs and JSON data rendering

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, pug, newline

I am trying to render a table at my index.jade page using arrays which are send using dates and product_count from index.js page.

```
        res.render('index', {
        title: 'Product Count (last 7 days)',
        keyy : dates,
        results: product_count
        });
```

At my index.jade page it is showing as :[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTBwY.png)

From the table, In each tablecells, the data is printing like this :

Amul Butter salted=2,Curd Milky Mist 200 gms=9,Curd Milky Mist 500 gms=15,Idli and Dosa Batter ID 1 Kg=12,Towness Baby Corn Peeled=4,Towness Banana Green Regular Semi Ripe=3,Towness Banana Yalakki Semi Ripe=1,Towness Bitter Gourd Medium=1,Towness Bottle Gourd Small=1,Towness Brinjal Long Green Medium=1,Towness Celery=2,Towness Chow Chow Medium Grade A=1,Towness European cucumber=7,Towness Garlic Peeled=1,

What I want to print this data , each separated by "," in different row, like this:

```
Amul Butter salted=2
Curd Milky Mist 200 gms=9
Curd Milky Mist 500 gms=15
Idli and Dosa Batter ID 1 Kg=12
Towness Baby Corn Peeled=4
Towness Banana Green Regular Semi Ripe=3
Towness Banana Yalakki Semi Ripe=1
Towness Bitter Gourd Medium=1
Towness Bottle Gourd Small=1
Towness Brinjal Long Green Medium=1
Towness Celery=2
Towness Chow Chow Medium Grade A=1
Towness European cucumber=7
Towness Garlic Peeled=1
```

I am pasting my array here, just help me how get each value in newline thats it.

`dates = [ 'May 17 2017', 'May 18 2017', 'May 19 2017', 'May 20 2017' ]`

```
product_count = [ 'Amul Butter salted=2,Curd Milky Mist 200 gms=9,Curd Milky Mist 500 gms=15,Idli and Dosa Batter ID 1 Kg=12,Towness Baby Corn Peeled=4,Towness Banana Green Regular Semi Ripe=3,Towness Banana Yalakki Semi Ripe=1,Towness Bitter Gourd Medium=1,Towness Bottle Gourd Small=1,Towness Brinjal Long Green Medium=1,Towness Celery=2,Towness Chow Chow Medium Grade A=1,Towness European cucumber=7,Towness Garlic Peeled=1,Towness Lemon  Medium =1,Towness Lettuce (Leafy Green)=5,Towness Mangalore Cucumber Medium=8,Towness Mint Leaves (Pudina Bunch)=2,Towness Musk Melon Stripes=1,Towness Onion Medium=1,Towness Papaya Raw=2,Towness Pumpkin Disco Town=3,Towness Raw Banana=1,Towness Red Radish (Long)=1,Towness Sambhar Onion=6,Towness Tomato Semi Ripe (Medium)=1',
  'Amul Butter salted=5,Curd Milky Mist 500 gms=11,Eggs Town  6 in 1=1,Paneer Nandini=2,Towness Banana Nendran Kerala Ripe=1,Towness Banana Yalakki Semi Ripe=10,Towness Bitter Gourd Medium=1,Towness Bread Multigrain Town 400 Gms=2,Towness Cluster beans=1,Towness Coriander Leaves=1,Towness European cucumber=1,Towness Ginger=1,Towness Lettuce (Ice Burg)=1,Towness Long Beans=2,Towness Mint Leaves (Pudina Bunch)=1,Towness Pumpkin Disco Town=1,Towness Red Cabbage=1,Towness Sambhar Onion=2',
  'Curd Milky Mist 500 gms=1,Hair Oil Coconut Parachute 250 Ml=1,Real Mixed Fruit 1 Ltr=1,Soda Lehar Evervess 500 Ml=1,Towness Alasande kai=1,Towness Banana Yalakki Semi Ripe=1,Towness Bread Multigrain Town 400 Gms=1,Towness Chutney Coconut Spicy=2,Towness Ginger=1,Towness Ladies Finger=1,Towness Nool Kol =1,Towness Sambhar Onion=1,Towness Tomato Semi Ripe (Medium)=1',
  'Naan Tawa (Half cooked) Town 5 Nos=1,Paneer Milky Mist 200 g=1,Real Mixed Fruit 1 Ltr=2,Towness Bread Kulcha=1,Towness Chikki Flax Seeds=2,Towness Chikki Melon seeds( Magaz)=2,Towness Coriander Leaves=7,Towness French Beans Grade A=6,Towness Ladies Finger=1,Towness Lemon  Medium =3,Towness Onion Medium=2,Towness Red Cabbage=1,Towness Sambhar Onion=1,Towness Tender Coconut=1,Towness Tomato Ripe (Medium)=1,Towness Tomato Semi Ripe (Medium)=1' ]
```

Please help me. If you have any doubt just mention it below.
I am totally online from now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get a possible solution for your case.

Your `res.render` function:

```
var result = [];
var tmp;
// change your , into break tags
for (var line in product_count) {
  result.push(product[line].replace(/,/g,'<br />'));
}
res.render('index', {
  title: 'Product Count (last 7 days)',
  keyy: dates,
  results: result,
});
```

Then, in your `jade` file:

```
table
  tr
    each val in keyy
      th= val
  tr
    each val in results
      td!= val
```

Bear in mind that your `product_count` has to be curated. Using `!=` may be used for `XSS` attacks.

A better solution would be to use a custom filter:
https://pugjs.org/language/filters.html

Hope it can help your situation.

Comment: That td!=val totally helped me.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.
Please can you mark my answer as solved?